# UTF-8 problem in response of SOAP request

Tags: java, xml, soap, utf-8

When I make the SOAP request from SOAP UI it returns normal answer, but when I try from Java code it returns not understandable characters. I tried to convert answer to UTF8 format, but it did not help. Please advise a solution, may be something wrong with my SOAP request. Example of response: **OÄžLU**, bu it must be **OĞLU** or **MÄ°KAYIL** instead of **MİKAYIL**

```
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            String userCredentials = username + ":" + password;
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");    
            con.setDoOutput(true);   
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(myXML);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.println(responseStatus);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            String xmlResponse = response.toString();
```

I tried:

```
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(xmlResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  String converted = new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Codepage-conversion has to be done on the Readers/Writers. Once you got a `String`it is already transformed to UTF-16. Your attempt is an often-seen idiom which - to be frank - does not make any sense at all. Also check whether your consoleot whatever you use to view the output () does support UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If it supports, what do you advise? Sorry I did not understand completely what you mean.

Comment: Make sure you know what Codepage is delivered by the service, set that when constructiong your `InputStreamReader` on the response. Specify the desired output-codepage when constructing the `OutputStreamWriter`, don't rely on defaults.

Comment: Is your Java project based on maven?

Comment: No, simple Java project. But I will change it to Maven and will use for some reasons if it will work properly.

Comment: I made it Maven project and it started to show all characters correctly. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

Comment: Tried, now it returns O?LU or M?KAYIL

Comment: I'll check it in my IDE for you.

Comment: Hi, I've tried my solution in my IDE. I wrote a simple servlet which responses with your string "OĞLU". System.out prints O?LU but if I'm debugging it, Eclipse's showing the right character. So: it works, it's only System.out that prints it wrong.

Comment: Thank you. Yes also I mentioned above in another comment, I converted it to Maven project and tried to show the value on the screen with html, it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try this?
`con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: Hello, thanks, I tried, does not help. Because, I think this line is for request and I don't have a problem with request, my problem is with response, when I print response get this ugly characters.

Comment: First I thought same, but it is interesting when I try from tool like SOAP UI it returns correct characters and this means on server side everything is ok.

Comment: @SamirAmanov Can you tell me the byte array returned by `buffer.array ()` in hexadecimal?  In this case, it seems to be the fastest to analyze the byte array.

Comment: It returned [B@53d8d10a

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding is set as part of the Content-Type header.

I believe you're accidentally mixing charsets, which is why it is not displaying properly.

Try adding the charset to `Content-Type` like so:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, I tried, does not help. Because, I think this line is for request and I don't have a problem with request, my problem is with response, when I print response get this ugly characters.